# Data structure: advanced string splitting to return a list

Tags: python, string, list, split

I'm writing a function called

get_coords(item) that takes as input a single string in the expected format of the Location 1 column in a data file. The function should return a list with two entries: the latitude and longitude as floating point values. If the latitude and longitude are missing, it should return numpy.nan (NaN) to indicate a missing value.

An example succesfull implementation would be:

```
text = '1533 Bridle Creek Blvd\nVirginia Beach, VA 23464-7907\n(36.787392, -76.15761)'
print(get_coords(text))
[36.787392, -76.15761]
```

I feel like I need to use some form of string splitting, however, the longitude and latitude coordinates can be of different lengths which makes me feel like I need to use something like the re module and use something like re.search;  how do I extract the coordinates and return them as a list, given different lengths of the coordinates as well as the initial string?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the coordinates are always in the last line. If this is the case, we can do the following:

```
coords_str = text.splitlines()[-1]
```

to get the last line.

Due to a lucky coincidence, it seems that the coordinates are formatted exactly like python tuples. because of that, we can use the `ast` module to transform it into a python tuple:

```
import ast
ast.literal_eval(coords_str)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `re`, here is a pattern:

```
return list(map(float, re.search(r'\(([+-]?[\d.]+),\s*([+-]?[\d.]+)\)', text).groups()))
```

In short, `re.search` for a pattern that:

- begins with open paren -> `\(`
- has an optional sign -> `[+-]?`
- has a series of digits and periods -> `[\d.]+`
- has a comma and optional whitespace -> `,\s*`
- repeats the number pattern -> `[+-]?[\d.]+`
- and ends with a close-paren `\)`

Note that the extra parentheses create matching groups that can be queried by the `.groups()` call later.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
def get_coords(str):
    latLong = str.split('\n')[-1]
    if not latLong:
        return numpy.nan
    latLong = latLong.replace("(","")
    latLong = latLong.replace(")","")
    latLongList = latLong.split(',')
    latLongList = list(map(float, latLongList))
    return latLongList
```

You might:

- **Split** the string **around '\n'**;
- Get the **last line** with Latitude and Longitude;

  - If values are missing, **return numpy.nan**;
- **Get rid** of characters like **"(" and ")"**;
- Split the results **around ","**;
- **Format** the values.

No need to worry about the different lenghts on the strings.